# Do not close the camera just because another activity that I launched is in the foreground temporarily

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, activity-lifecycle

I have a very stable application using the camera where I call camera.open() in onResume() and camera.release() in onDestroy() of my activity.

This is well and good, until I do some small task that requires another activity to be launched over the top of mine, such as getting the user to select a contact.

The problem is that as soon as my activity loses the foreground, onDestroy() is called which closes the camera.  Then as soon as the user has selected the contact, we go back to my activity and the camera opens again.

I want to call the contacts app to select a contact without it closing the camera, but I also need to close the camera cleanly when my app is being legitimately shut down via back button, or home button, or something else.

This is a problem because the device is the samsung galaxy camera, and opening and closing the camera takes about 2 seconds for each phase, and also extends the lens out somewhat, which can be annoying if you are holding the device in your hand.

Any suggestions on how I can distinguish between a genuine closing of my app, and simply being placed in the background because of another activity that I called ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered select the contact first then go to whatever activity that interact with the camera?

Comment: Yes I have, but that does not work for me, as I need to take advantage of the time it takes to select the contact to start uploading the images taken with the camera for processing on the server.